# Access port 8000 on digitalocean nginx server

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, digital-ocean

I have a flask app running on port 8000 of my droplet on digital ocean. I needed to enable ssl on this server with Nginx, and I can connect to my main port without any problem. But when trying to connect to funders-api.ninja:8000 I can't get access. Here's my default config

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    listen [::]:8000 ssl;
    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/funders-api.ninja/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = www.funders-api.ninja) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = funders-api.ninja) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is basicly de config made with Cerbot, but I would like to acces port 8000 com https.

Answer (score 1):

thats a misconfigured section - the `example.com` server section is commented out in your config file, and at port 8000 you are listening with server name of `funders-api.ninja www.funders-api.ninja`

Comment: Sorry, I eddited my question, I want to connect with funders-api.ninja:8000

Comment: @LuccasParoni which error do you see when you `curl` to `funders-api.ninja:8000`?

Comment: I think I kinda solved it, I wasant restarting nginx properly, but now, my 8000 port is https, but I cant restart my flask app on port 8000 because there is already another process there..

Comment: can you not kill it? `sudo fuser -n tcp -k 8000`

Comment: I can, but the process running on 8000 is the Nginx process, and I need it to have https on that port, dont I?

Comment: @LuccasParoni you didnt tell which error do you see when you curl to funders-api.ninja:8000?